# Wordpress- Checking for available value before adding profile info to Author Box

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I made a simple Wordpress theme and I'm using an author box at the bottom of posts. It currently displays a name, which links to search results for all posts by the author, and it shows their bio. I want to add links to the bottom that output links to all of the 'Contact Info.' The options for this theme will be Email, Yahoo IM, Jabber, AIM, Twitter, Facebook, and Google +.

I know I can use `<?php the_author_meta('thing'); ?>` to kick out links to each. But I want it to check if those fields are filled out, for each, before making the links. How can I do this with brewed-in Wordpress goodies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test if the fields are set with:

```
<?php 

$value=get_the_author_meta( $field, $userID ); 

if(strlen($value)>0){
    // do stuff
}
?>
```